# Android: BottomNavigationView first fragment switch is super delayed

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

Attempting to use a bottom nav view, the standard view provided by android. The first time I click on any fragment, it's a SUPER delayed UI reaction time (about 2 seconds until the ripple, item selection update, and new fragment show)
It's only the first time I switch to any fragment, after that, it behaves as expected.

I found a similar question already on here, but there were zero suggestions or answers. [See that post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650599/bottom-navigation-loading-fragments-is-slow?rq=1)

Find below the logic I user for switching the fragments.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    bottom_nav_bar.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_nav_bar_menu)
    bottom_nav_bar.selectedItemId = R.id.nav_summary

    bottom_nav_bar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
        when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_1-> startFragment1()
            R.id.nav_2 -> startFragment2()
            else -> startFragment3()
        }
        true
    }
}

fun startFragment1() = replaceFragment(Fragment1(), "TAG1")

fun startFragment2() = replaceFragment(Fragment2(), "TAG2")

fun startFragment3() = replaceFragment(Fragment3(), "TAG3")

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, fragmentTag: String) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fade_in, R.animator.fade_out)
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragmentTag)
            .commit()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
supportfragmentmanager
```

instead of just normal FragmentManager. It’s smoother. Of course you have to change to imports to v4 Fragment but after that it should work better. I was having all kinds of weird stuff happen till I made that switch.